# Angularjs how to get constant in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I get constant in controller.

```
 angular.module('app').register.controller('navigationCtrl', function ($scope, navigationSvc, $STORAGE_KEY) {
    alert($STORAGE_KEY);
```

$STORAGE_KEY is constant variable. I want get it without injecting. I want something like:

```
angular.constant('$STORAGE_KEY')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
angular.module('app').constant('$STORAGE_KEY', {
  value : 'myval'
});
```

And you can call her by your controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('navigationCtrl', ['$STORAGE_KEY',function($STORAGE_KEY){
 alert($STORAGE_KEYS.value);
}]);
```

Don t forget that a change on the value of your constant will be applied everywhere in your angular's module.

Answer (score 1):

You can create object containing all keys like :

```
var keys = {
    $STORAGE_A: 'a',
    $STORAGE_B: 'b',
    $STORAGE_C: 'c',
    $STORAGE_D: 'd',

}
```

add this object to your app:

```
angular.module('app').value('keys', keys);
```

and after that inject only one keys to conntrolles and easy access all your keys ie:

```
angular.module('app').controller(['$scope', 'keys', function ($scope, keys) {

    //ie
    $scope.keya = keys.$STORAGE_A



}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the constant in your module:

```
angular.module('app').constant('$STORAGE_KEY', 'your_constant_value');
```

You can see an example in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zpJaP13VCC2EeWJ0S2w6?p=preview)

And in [Angular's module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

Comment: I have known that. I want when controller don't need inject that key, we can get this value. Because as you know, may be in controller I have 50 keys constant and I must inject all keys to controller. Something like: angular.module('app').constant('$STORAGE_KEY')

Comment: Ok. As far as I know you have to inject your needs. Maybe you can group your constants in objects.